# IntelliJ IDEA closure indent settings

Tags: coding-style, intellij-idea, settings, indentation

Is there a setting for closure indentation in IC?

I want this(default IDEA way)

```
deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new

                                   OnClickListener() {
                                       @Override
                                       public void onClick(View view) {
                                           onDeleteClicked(view);
                                       }
                                   });
```

to look like this(default Eclipse way)

```
deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onDeleteClicked();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Looks like http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-4421.

Comment: Haven't found the issue on their tracker myself. Thanks. Btw, I'll accept this as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known bug of the Clojure plug-in [logged in YouTrack](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-4421). Feel free to star/vote.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior can be overriden with [Eclipse Code Formatter](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?idea&id=6546) plugin